# How to check number of commands that redis has not processed yet

Tags: database, redis, redis-commands

I am trying to do monitoring redis database. I'm using telegraf, influxdb and grafana to monitor it. now, I want to check number and type of commands which are pending to process.
I check this page here,
[Redis commands queue size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372382/redis-commands-queue-size). It helped alot, but I hope I can get more information, like number and type of commands as I write. is there any way to check it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there are some commands start with 'X' at redis client https://redis.io/commands

I think this is what I want, so i'm looking at it now

Comment: NO. Command starts with `X` are related to Redis Stream. It has nothing to do with your problem.